# How to solve distorted black colors in Chrome?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, debian, colors

I installed Debian 9 on my laptop, The black colors look bad or distorted (sorry, I don't know what to call it)

The hair of the man on the left and the black jacket of the man on the right doesn't look good:

[image]

I have this problem only in Chrome when running Debian.

Here is another screenshot from Firefox, the black colors here look good.

[image]

I tried reinstalling the Nvidia driver and Chrome but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please google for `chromium+gamma` and/or `chrome+gamma`.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it, I have been searching for a solution for the past days but couldn't find any.

Comment: Sorry, no: I do not experience this problem over there with Chromium 60.0.3112.78 running on Debian Stretch (9.1) amd64. Should you google for the keywords I hinted at, you'd come up with a number of bug reports and discussions; I'd recommend chiming in into them. Your issue appears to me to be rather peculiar and narrow, so it's best to ask folks close to the development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing the Nvidia driver using these instructions in the Debian wiki https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee

I installed Bumblebee because I have an optimus laptop, but if you don't you can follow these instructions https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

Edit: I don't have this problem in KDE.